# Where does QEMU maps the kernel pages of a guest OS?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, mapping, qemu

I am reading some QEMU's source code (on 3.1.0 version but hints to other version are accepted as well) and I am trying to understand/find at which point in the source code does the QEMU maps the the guest's OS kernel memory in the host's machine memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QEMU doesn't specifically map the guest OS kernel itself. It just provides emulated RAM to the virtual machine (and this emulated RAM is created by doing a normal anonymous mmap in qemu_anon_ram_alloc() -- it could equally well do it by calling malloc()). Guest binaries may be loaded into the RAM either by QEMU (the various hw/core/loader.c functions do this) or by the guest itself loading it off emulated disk.

For an x86 guest, typically QEMU only loads the guest BIOS rom image into the guest memory. The guest BIOS then loads the actual guest kernel into memory (either from emulated disk, or via the "fw_cfg" QEMU-specific device that the guest can use to access files from outside the emulation), and QEMU doesn't know or care where it happens to have put it.